# Apex DateTime to String then pass the argument

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two Visualforce pages, and for several reasons I've decided it is best to pass a datetime value between them as a string.  However, after my implementation my date always appear to be null even though my code seems to compile.

I have researched quite a few formatting topics but unfortunately each variation of the format() on date time seems to not produce different results.

The controller on page 1 declares two public variables

```
public datetime qcdate;
public String fdt;
```

qcdate is generated from a SOQL query.

```
 wo = [SELECT id, WorkOrderNumber, Quality_Control_Timestamp__c FROM WorkOrder WHERE id=:woid];
 qcdate = wo.Quality_Control_Timestamp__c;
```

fdt is then generated from a method

```
fdt = getMyFormattedDate(qcdate);
```

which looks like this

```
public String getMyFormattedDate(datetime dt){
    return dt.format();    }
```

fdt is then passed in the URL to my next VF page.

```
String url = '/apex/workordermaintenanceinvoice?tenlan='+tenlan +'&woid=' + woid + '&invnum=' + invnum + '&addr1=' + addr1 + 'fdt=' + fdt;
PageReference pr = new PageReference(url);
```

I expected when calling `{!fdt}` on my next page to get a proper string.  But I do not.

UPDATE:

Sorry I guess I should not have assumed that it was taken for granted that the passed variable was called correctly.  Once the variable is passed the following happens:

The new page controller creates the variable:

```
public String fdt
```

The variable is captured with a getparameters().

```
fdt = apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('fdt');
```

The getfdt() method is created

```
public String getfdt(){
    return fdt;
}
```

Which is then called on the VF page

{!fdt}

This all of course still yields a 'blank' date which is the mystery I'm still trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed it via URL, cool. But... so what? Page params don't get magically parsed into class variables on the target page. Like if you have a record-specific page and you know in the url there's `/apex/SomePage?id=001....` - that doesn't automatically mean your VF page will have anything in `{!id}` or that your apex controller (if there's any) will have `id` class variable. The only "magic" thing you get in apex is the standard controller and hopefully it'll have something in sc.getId() but that's it.

In fact it'd be very stupid and dangerous. Imagine code like `Integer integer = 5`, that'd be fun to debug, in next line you type "integer" and what would that be, the type or variable? Having a variable named "id" would be bad idea too.

If you want to access the `fdt` URL param in target page in pure Visualforce, something like [`{!$CurrentPage.parameters.fdt}`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_currentpage.htm) should work OK. If you need it in Apex - you'll have to parse it out of the URL. Similar thing, [`ApexPages.currentPage()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_ApexPages_currentPage.htm) and then call [`getParameters()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_System_PageReference_getParameters.htm) on it.

(Similarly it's cleaner to set parameters that way too, not hand-crafting the URL and "&" signs manually. If you do it manual you theoretically should escape special characters... Let apex do it for you.

Comment: Thanks.  I did not mean to imply that the {!fdt} was then called in the future page without first assigning it to the custom controller on the 2nd page.  Please see the update above as I set FDT with a getparameters() and called it.  Yet it is still blank when I try to display it.

Comment: Right :) You have a typo. `...addr1 + 'fdt=' + fdt;` doesn't contain '&'. Looks like your value gets appended to end of address. That's why it's better to compose urls with getParameters() too, something like `getParameters().putAll(new Map<String, String>{'tenlan' => tenlan, 'woid' => woid, 'invnum' => invnum, ...});` And it'll take care of escaping special chars for you.

Comment: Yep.  Defeated by an '&'.  Thank you very much.  Frustrating that I keep getting shut down by such trivial things.  Once I wrap up this project I'll look into using proper parameter setting as you suggested.